# Scala map a field in a Map to another field in the Map

Tags: scala

I've got a case where I need to map some fields in my map into some other fields in the Map but I don't know how to do this.

Something like this...

```
m match {
 case m["key1"] => m["key1"] = m["key10"]
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Huh? "map a field into a field"? What's `m[0]`? Show some code that actually compiles

Comment: @Dima - Yea, that's just trying to explain what I need to do.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it...

```
...
m map {
      case (key, value) => key match {
        case "userId" => (key, m("p_studentId"))
        ...
      }

    }
```

Comment: No, this will trow a runtime error. 
If you just want to replace a value for a key, this should do it: `m.updated("userId", m("p_studentId"))`